# water line on same meter/panel post

Tags: water

Can I have my water spigot at/attached on the same post (6x6 or 6x8) as my meter/panel combo and RV panel? Meter/panel on one side, RV panel on opposite side and an auto drain frost proof hydrants on the one side not used.

Comment: Just runs out of words...

Comment: @solarmike - extra text that was removed.

Comment: I don't know of any NEC codes regarding this, but there may be local regulations. You should check with local inspectors or competent electricians.   The problem I've run into sometimes with inspectors when you ask a question before installation, depending upon the personality of the inspector, is sometimes they just say: "It's not my job to give you advice, after installation when I inspect, I'll let you know". Gov't at it's finest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have the spigot on the same post but not normally on the same side.
RV parks regularly have the water at the same location. It’s like having a water heater adjacent to the main panel in a home there are some that think it is a code violation but it is not.